# How to create dynamic forms in React. There are some dynamic fields inside of dynamic fields

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object, react-state-management

I want to create dynamic forms, it has name, desc and multiple sections, each section has multiple questions, each question has multiple options. when I click some buttons, it should create form items dynamically. Such as, firstly I enter detalils for name, desc sections. After I enter details fo question when I saved question it open new form enter another questions. After saving questions, I want to add new section as result structure ob array would like this. It is dynamic when you save question or section, it create another question or section.

```js
const [data, setData] = useState([
    {
      name: "",
      desc: "",
      sections: [
        {
          sectionName: "",
          sectionDesc: "",
          questions: [
            {
              questionType: "",
              questionText: "",
              options: [],
              answer: "",
            },
            {
              questionType: "",
              questionText: "",
              options: [],
              answer: "",
            },

          ],
        },
        {
          sectionName: "",
          sectionDesc: "",
          questions: [
            {
              questionType: "",
              questionText: "",
              options: [],
              answer: "",
            },
            {
              questionType: "",
              questionText: "",
              options: [],
              answer: "",
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  ]);
```

For now, I created simple array, but I want to this as dynamic as it like the explation

```js
const [data, setData] = useState([
    {
      name: "",
      desc: "",
      sections: [
        {
          sectionName: "",
          sectionDesc: "",
          questions: [
            {
              questionType: "",
              questionText: "",
              options: [],
              answer: "",
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  ]);
```

I need handleChange function and addFields in specific fields, sharing links would be great
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

for handleChange the cleaniest way is using [loadash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#set)

```js
 const [data, setData] = useState([
    {
      name: "",
      desc: "",
      sections: [
        {
          sectionName: "",
          sectionDesc: "",
          questions: [
            {
              questionType: "",
              questionText: "",
              options: [],
              answer: "",
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  ]);

  const handleChange = (path, value) => {
    setData(_.set(data, path, value));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    handleChange("[0].sections[0].questions[0].answer", "A");
    handleChange("[0].sections[0].questions[1].answer", "A");
  }, []);

  console.log(data);
```

inserting data in specific fields:

```js
setData((prevState) => [
    ...prevState,
    {
      name: "",
      desc: "",
      sections: [
        {
          sectionName: "",
          sectionDesc: "",
          questions: [
            {
              questionType: "",
              questionText: "",
              options: [],
              answer: "",
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  ]);
```

Comment: in second example we use [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and [functional updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates)